# Is __enter__ and __exit__ behaviour for connection objects specified in the Python database API?

Tags: python, database, api, mysql-python, specifications

## Background

I recently discovered the Python `with` keyword and started seeing its potential usefulness for more prettily handling some scenarios where I'd previously have used `try: ... finally: ...` constructs. I immediately decided to try it out on the MySQLdb connection object in some code I was writing.

I didn't bother reading up on how `__enter__` and `__exit__` behave in implementors of the Python database API, and naively expected the behaviour to be like that of file objects - all I was expecting was for exit to call `connection.close()`.

Imagine my confusion, then, at this behaviour:

```
>>> with util.get_db_connection() as conn:
...     print conn
... 
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0xb6ca8b4c>
```

`get_db_connection()` returns a MySQLdb connection object, but the `__enter__` method of that connection object returns a cursor object, not the connection object itself like I was expecting given how `__enter__` and `__exit__` work for file objects. I guess I ought to be doing `with util.get_db_connection() as cursor:`, or else not using `with` at all.

## Questions

Immediately this discovery makes me wonder a few things:

1. What else do the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of MySQLdb connection objects do? Is `__exit__` going to magically commit or rollback changes for me without me explicitly asking for that to happen? Is there anything else non-obvious that I should know?
2. Is this behaviour the same in other implementers of the Python database API (like sqlite3, django, or psycopg2)?
3. Is this behaviour formally specced anywhere? `ctrl-f`ing the latest spec ([PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)) for 'enter', 'exit' and 'context manager' doesn't throw up anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Python DBAPI was written well before context managers were added to the Python language.

As such, different database libraries made their *own* decisions on how to implement context manager support (if they implemented it at all).

*Usually* using the database as a context manager ties you to a transaction. The transaction is started on `__enter__`, and committed or aborted on `__exit__`, depending on wether or not there was an exception. As such, you are supposed to use the MySQL connection as a context manager after connecting seperately:

```
connection = util.get_db_connection()

with connection as cursor:
    cursor.execute(...)

# connection commit is issued if no exceptions were raised.
```

The [`sqlite3` context manager implementation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) is subtly different; it also manages transactions, but does not return a cursor from the `__enter__` method:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
with con:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    # or use the connection directly
    con.execute(...)
```

Technically, it just returns `self` on `__enter__`.

Comment: For MySQL, I often do `with contextmanager.closing(db()) as d, d as c:` in order to get auto-closing *and* a transaction.

Answer (score -1):

See the `__enter__` function in this link.
https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/connections.py

`__enter__` function of connection object returns `self.cursor()`.

That is why you are getting cursor object instead of Connection object.