# Sqlite insert query not working with python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been trying to insert data into the database using the following code in python:

```
import sqlite3 as db
conn = db.connect('insertlinks.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
db.autocommit(True)
a="asd"
b="adasd"
cursor.execute("Insert into links (link,id) values (?,?)",(a,b))
conn.close()
```

The code runs without any errors. But no updation to the database takes place. I tried adding the `conn.commit()` but it gives an error saying module not found. Please help?

Comment: I am not sure: is it possible that you need to set auto-commit before obtaining the cursor?

Comment: tried that as well. get the same error 'module' object has no attribute 'autocommit'

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'autocommit'`. There is no such method on the `sqlite3` module, setting autocommit would work quite differently.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What should I do if i cant use autocommit?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You do have to commit after inserting:

```
cursor.execute("Insert into links (link,id) values (?,?)",(a,b))
conn.commit()
```

or use the [connection as a context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager):

```
with conn:
    cursor.execute("Insert into links (link,id) values (?,?)", (a, b))
```

or set autocommit correctly by setting the `isolation_level` keyword parameter to the `connect()` method to `None`:

```
conn = db.connect('insertlinks.db', isolation_level=None)
```

See [Controlling Transactions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).

Comment: commit is giving an error. However, the second code worked fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does the `__exit__` call `commit`? Is this part of the DB-API spec?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Yes, the context manager `__exit__` method calls `commit()`. This is an extension, there were no context managers when the API was written, see [Is \_\_enter\_\_ and \_\_exit\_\_ behaviour for connection objects specified in the Python database API?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15568275)

Answer (score 4):

It can be a bit late but set the `autocommit = true` save my time! especially if you have a script to run some bulk action as `update/insert/delete`...

**Reference:** https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level

it is the way I usually have in my scripts:

```
def get_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('../db.sqlite3', isolation_level=None)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return conn, cursor

def get_jobs():
    conn, cursor = get_connection()

    if conn is None:
        raise DatabaseError("Could not get connection")
```

I hope it helps you!