# Sqlite insert result doesn't show on the next immediate select command

Tags: python, sqlite

```
cur = self.db.execute("insert into HiddenNode%d (createKey) values ('%s')" % (i, preNewNode))
print 'Added new node in HiddenNode%d: %s' % (i, preNewNode)
self.db.commit()

test = self.db.execute("select * from HiddenNode2").fetchall()[0]
print test
```

This code generates output as below:

```
Added new node in HiddenNode2: 1_2_3
!!!!!
(u'1_2',)
```

It looks like the insert doesn't happen at all. But after the call finish. It does commit all changes to the database. On connecting to database, I specified isolation_level = 'IMMEDIATE' and set auto commit to true.

Related issue is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488763/sqlite-insert-query-not-working-with-python). But I have tried both answers. None solves my problem on my side.

Any way to get the insert appear right after the operation?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `cur.commit()` instead?

Comment: It should be database calling commit, not the result