# update sqlite rows using loops

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to update rows from a Sqlite database based on certain conditions.
My code isn't returning any errors but my sqlite rows aren't being updated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

with sqlite3.connect("911.db",timeout=10) as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()
    #go and fetch all links in DB
    c.execute("SELECT url FROM Links")

#for each link I am going to see if it contains the div class "flashmessage warning"
for link in c:
    page = requests.get(link[0])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    status = soup.find_all('div', class_='flashmessage warning')
    #check if list is not empty. If it is not then update value for update_row
    if not status:
        update_row = link[0]
        d = connection.cursor()
        d.execute("UPDATE Links SET status = 0 WHERE url == (?)", (update_row,) )
        d.execute("UPDATE Links SET last_seen = (?) WHERE url == (?)", (today, update_row) )
    #if list is not empty then update status with 1
    else:
        update_row = link[0]
        e = connection.cursor()
        e.execute("UPDATE Links SET status = 1 WHERE url == (?)", (update_row,) )
```

Comment: After update queries you forgot to do commit

Comment: You must not modify data that you're iterating over with a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use

```
with sqlite3.connect("911.db",timeout=10, isolation_level=None) as connection:
```

adding the isolation_level=None solved the problem as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488763/sqlite-insert-query-not-working-with-python)