# Not getting data from database in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I have tried getting the registered data from a database the program has created when first run.

**database.py**

```
import sqlite3

CREATE_TABLE = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS college (
                                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                    FirstName TEXT,
                                    SecondName TEXT,
                                    Position TEXT);"""

INSERT_DATA = "INSERT INTO college (FirstName, SecondName, Position) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
DISPLAY_DATA = "SELECT * FROM college WHERE Position = ?;"
def connect():
    return sqlite3.connect('databas.db')

def create_table(connection):
    with connection:
        connection.execute(CREATE_TABLE)

def insert_data(connection, FirstName, SecondName, Position):
    with connection:
        connection.execute(INSERT_DATA, (FirstName, SecondName, Position))

def request_data(connection, position):
    with connection:
        return connection.execute(DISPLAY_DATA, (position,)).fetchall()
```

**api.py**

```
import database

API_MENU = """
--- Student Database ---

1) Register new student
2) Delete
3) Show students

4) Register new staff
5) Delete
6) Show staff

7) >> Quit the program

Your choice: """
def main():
    connection = database.connect()
    database.create_table(connection)

    
    while (choice := input(API_MENU)) != "7":
        if choice == "1":
            FirstName = "Julius"
            SecondName = "Jessie"
            Position = "Student"

            database.insert_data(connection, FirstName, SecondName, Position)
        elif choice == "2":
            database.request_data(connection, "Student")
        elif choice == "3":
            pass
        elif choice == "4":
            pass
        elif choice == "5":
            pass
        elif choice == "6":
            pass
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again!")

main()
```

I am simply not being returned any data after I have registered the data using option 1. When running the code and choosing option 1, you should input a name, surname and position (Student / Staff) and then write that to the database (i have just defined strings for the purpose of putting the code here) and then choosing the option 2 should return the data that has "Student" as a position however it does not return any data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sqlite insert query not working with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488763/sqlite-insert-query-not-working-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was simply negligent with actually using the function print() to show the data.

```
database.request_data(connection, "Student")
```

The line above should be:

```
print(database.request_data(connection, "Student"))
```