# Can you use a context manager to write a pandas DataFrame to sqlite

Tags: python, sql, pandas

When writing a pandas DataFrame to sql, would it be possible to use the with statement in the following way?

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table", conn)
    
    # add change to db

    df.to_sql('table', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: Curious, did you try your code? If so, please post error or undesired result.

Comment: The code worked without errors, but I'm wondering if that is the right way to do it in python.

Comment: Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15568137/1422451). Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed

#### Example:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

# Return the result as a list
with con:
    result = con.execute("SELECT * FROM table").fetchall()

# Pass as engine to pandas 
with con:
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table", con)

# Close connection
con.close()
```

### Edit

As @Parfait has rightly pointed out the context manager is on transactions made by the connection, thus the `con` object should closed manually.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, isn't the connection closed automatically when you use a context manager? Would I run into problems if the con.close() part is left out?

Comment: Ideally, @MiguelTrejo should have linked the [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager). Context manager implemented here is not on connection object but transactions made on the connection. You still need to `con.close` at end. See example in docs.